# Javascript not performing Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I have a HTML page which i am running on localhost. I want to access some data from a Python script and use it in my HTML page, The Ajax call in the function doesn't work, If i remove it the program runs perfectly. Any help?

Javascript Function :

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript" ></script> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="LoginStyle.css" type="text/css" />

 <script type = "text/javascript" >
function getData()
{
//Code doesn't even enter this function but when i remove the $.ajax part it enters the function
alert("I AM HERE");

$.ajax(
{
type: "GET",
url: "/cgi-bin/check.py" // Path of the script/code i want to run
success: function(response)
{
    $("#username").text(data); //this is where i should get the response, Not sure about the syntax i.e. whether i should 
//output in a <div> tag or a text box

}
});
}
```

Calling the Function in HTML like this:

```
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="getData();return false;"">
<input id="Uname" name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" />
```

Python Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from StringIO import StringIO
import json

def htmlData():
    content=json.loads('{"access": {"token": {"issued_at": "2013-04-18T14:40:23.299903", "expires": "2013-04-19T14:40:23Z", "id": "4c5ef01f52c7404fb5324c520d25d1fe"}}}')
data=json.dumps(content, indent=4, separators = (', ', ': '))
    print data
    return

htmlData()
```

Comment: look at the console....there could be some syntx errors

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: post full stacktrace.

Comment: I corrected the syntax error, But I still can't get the response from the python script, Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: I am getting this in my error log "[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: check.py"

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `,` in the url property

```
function getData() {
    //Code does not even enter this function but when i remove the $.ajax part it enters the function
    alert("I AM HERE");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //--> here missing , in url
        url: "/cgi-bin/check.py", // Path of the script/code i want to run
        success: function (response) {
            $("#username").text(data); //this is where i should get the response, Not sure about the syntax i.e. whether i should 
            //output in a <div> tag or a text box

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using, you have missed to add `,` end of url string

```
url: "/cgi-bin/check.py",
```

instead of

```
 url: "/cgi-bin/check.py"
```